# How to remove a cookie on logout button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am having a hard time removing a cookie when the logout button is clicked. I currently have a logout button with the class logout. and this is the simple jquery line I am trying to put to remove the cookie but it is not working.

```
$('button .logout').click(function () {
            $.cookie('userid', null);
       };
```

userid is the name of the cookie.

Oh I am using a signed cookie, not sure if that changes anything?

EDIT:

Here is how I set the cookie:

```
exports.loginPost = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("here 1");
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err) }
        if (!user) { 
            return res.render('loginError', {title: 'Weblio'}); }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
            res.cookie('userid', user._id, { maxAge: 900000, signed: true });
            res.redirect('userProfile');
        });
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

And using a simple express - node js cookieParser with a secret in it.

Comment: For security reasons, authentication cookies should be marked as HTTP Only, which means they aren't accessible from javascript and need to be cleared on the server.

Comment: Ok, so do I render a logout page and remove the cookie during the render or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give it negative time and just set the value to nothing.

Hmm, try:

```
$('button .logout').click(function () {
    $.cookie('userid', "", -1);
});
```

Comment: oh sorry forgot to mention this, it is a signed cookie does that change anything?

Comment: @Lion789 It shouldn't matter.

Comment: No errors, ok I added how I am going about setting the cookie if that helps

Comment: @Lion789 Wait, i'm confused. So you are setting it with `Node.js` and trying to delete it using `jQuery/JavaScript`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33461/discussion-between-shawn31313-and-lion789)